# redirect issue in password update in laravel fortify

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-fortify

I am working on Laravel Fortify. I want to update the user password using the current_password. there is a password. update route exists. but when i submit the form it redirects me to the home page instead of redirecting the the same route profile.edit.
Any help?

I don't know how to customize the redirections in fortify, as first time i am using it.